# Cant install tensorflow on windows 11

Tags: python

```
pip install tensorflow
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I tried to install tensorflow using pip, but its giving me an error, am using Python3.12

Comment: `tensorflow` is supported for python 3.12 yet. You need to install python 3.11 separately to use `tensorflow`